# How to handle all requests as filter context in Express?

Tags: express

Checking Express docs I saw this kind of solution below:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Intercepting requests...');
});
```

Its really intercept the request and output on the console the message. The problem is the execution process of the site doesn't stop, the request doesn't ends and seems to be in a kind of loop. There is another way to simulate filters on Express or can't do it right now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add `next` as a parameter to your function and then call it inside when you're done with logging

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Intercepting requests ...');
  next();  // call next() here to move on to next middleware/router
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much, zeMirco. I never noticed the next() function before. So, about the green mark I don´t realize where it is. How can I check or mark it?

Comment: I checked out the comment of @JohnnyHK and I did it. Ty!

Comment: all good! the `next` parameter in express is optional. You can have middleware with or without the parameter.